# How to set the Text for Search Dialog - Android

Tags: android

Can some one assist in advising me on how to set a specific text to the Search Dialog?  I know how to set a "hint", I do this through the xml file.  But I would like to set the text to the Search dialog according to what was last searched for. I plan on retrieving this through SharedPreference.  I just do not know how to set the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass the query string as intent extra and in your Search Activity, retrieve it as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```

Reference - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ReceivingTheQuery

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand how to retrieve the search query, what I meant was how do i display the search term in the dialog box that was last searched for. For example, a person types in "Tony Blair", presses search, a connection problem ensues, but his search term is still present and visible in the search dialog.  He therefore does not have to type it in again...I just do not know how to set a text to the search dialog.