# Is it workable/ good practice to have the same fragment hosted by two different Activities?

Tags: android

I would like to use the same fragment on two different Activities. Is this workable/ good practice?

Comment: Yes. It was the original foundation for fragments (making sections of code modular/reusable).

Comment: i understand that its fine and can be very advantageous to hold multiple fragments in the same Activity. Wasn't sure whether the other way round was sound or not...

Comment: Yea, the idea is so that you can use the same fragment in multiple places to avoid having to redundantly code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reusing fragments is highly encouraged.

Quote from [official source](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design)

> You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity
>   component. That is, because each fragment defines its own layout and
>   its own behavior with its own lifecycle callbacks, you can include one
>   fragment in multiple activities, so you should design for reuse and
>   avoid directly manipulating one fragment from another fragment.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Is it possible for you to have a look at this other question i have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260924/how-to-set-the-text-for-search-dialog-android/27261160#27261160